# Laravel change log path

Tags: laravel

I'm using the following change my log path:

```
\Log::useDailyFiles(...)
```

But I still get log entries in `/storage/logs/`. How can I use only my log path?

Answer (score 3):

Laravel already registers an instance of the logger when bootstrapping the [`ConfigureLogging`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/ConfigureLogging.php) class. So when you use `Log::useDailyFiles()` you're just adding an additional log handler, that's why you also get log entries in the standard `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

To override the default log handler, Laravel offers the `configureMonologUsing` method available on the application instance. So in your `bootstrap/app.php` file just before the `return $app;` statement, add the following:

```php
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) use ($app) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(
        (new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(
            // Set the log path
            '/custom/path/to/custom.log',
            // Set the number of daily files you want to keep
            $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 5)
        ))->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true))
    );
});
```

The second parameter passed to the `RotatingFileHandler` tries to get a configuration value for `log_max_files` from `config/app.php` to determine how many daily log files it should keep, and if it doesn't find one it defaults to `5`. If you want to keep an unlimited number of daily log files just pass `0` instead.

---

You can read more about logging configuration in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration).

Comment: thank a lot, i try it, but i got Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application ,why ? i have no idea

Comment: What Laravel version are you using? Also please post the entire error stack trace which should include the file and line number  where the error is triggered, as well as specifying what piece of code is on that line. I have used this code before and it works just fine.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.5 and this works for me. Thanks alot

Comment: Additionally, you may want to allow stacktraces in your log, you can do this by pulling out the line formatter 
`$lineFormatter = new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true);
$lineFormatter->includeStacktraces(true);`

Answer (score 0):

> **Laravel 5  : bootstrap/app.php**

#### CUSTOM DAILY LOG :

```php
     $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) use ($app) {
         $monolog->pushHandler(
             (new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(
                 // Set the log path
                 $app->storagePath().'/logs/app_error.log',
                 // Set the number of daily files you want to keep
                 $app->make('config')->get('app.log_max_files', 30)
             ))->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true))
         );
     });
```

#### SINGLE LOG :

```php
    $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) use ($app) {
        $handler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($app->storagePath().'/logs/app_error.log');
        $handler->setFormatter(new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
        $monolog->pushHandler($handler);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still coming across this post, I believe changing your log file location is now easier in newer versions of Laravel. I am currently using 8.x.

In your `/config/logging.php`, you can define the `path` for your single and daily logs. Then, update whichever one you are looking to change.

```
'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => "/your/desired/log/path/file.log", // edit here
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
],

'daily' => [
    'driver' => 'daily',
    'path' => "/your/desired/log/path/file.log", // edit here
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    'days' => 14,
]
```

Comment: The path you specify will be relative to `/storage`. For example `/var/log/laravel` will log to `/storage/var/log/laravel`